# How can I sync a list of indivdual files?

Tags: sync

Given that I normally use Unison, what's the best way to sync a list of individual files?  Ideas I've had are:

1. Use rsync (Yuck! Pretty messy and complex compared to Unison.)
2. Create a subdirectory that holds links to the files in question and sync the subdirectory. ( Kludgy but it might work. )
3. Use some app I've not yet heard of suggested by the community.

Problem: I've a small set of interrelated profile scripts that look like this:

```
~/.bash_aliases_personal.sh 
~/.bash_aliases_professional.sh 
~/.gitconfig
```

They get changed on both machines.

Comment: Unison has what they call "preferences". A profile with the preferences `path`, `ignore` and `ignorenot` in suitable combination might help; see the [documentation](https://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/unison/download/releases/stable/unison-manual.html#prefs).

Comment: "Preferences" was close enough but you don't use ignore / ignorenot. You use a list of path = for reasons mentioned in the documentation. Post as answer and I will give you the cheddar.